# Logical OR evaluates all expression in Bash script

Tags: bash

Consider this simple shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

exp1="[ $1 -gt 5 ]";
exp2="[ `ping localhost -c 4 | wc -l` -gt 0 ]";

if eval $exp1 || eval $exp2
then
   echo Ok!
fi
```

I was expecting that passing `10` to this script, the ping was not executed, but it is clearly executed (since the script takes some seconds to write "Ok!").

I was wondering if there is a way to avoid/optimize this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will execute `ping` because you have:

```
exp2="[ `ping localhost -c 4 | wc -l` -gt 0 ]";
```

which uses command substitution *before* evaluating the condition due to **double quotes**.

Use **single quotes** to delay the execution until the `eval` line, like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

exp1='[[ $1 -gt 5 ]]'
exp2='[[ $(ping localhost -c 4 | wc -l) -gt 0 ]]'

if eval $exp1 || eval $exp2
then
   echo Ok!
fi
```

Better yet, use **functions**. [Don't store commands in variables!](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ#BashFAQ.2F050.I.27m_trying_to_put_a_command_in_a_variable.2C_but_the_complex_cases_always_fail.21)

```
exp1() { [[ $1 -gt 5 ]]; }
exp2() { [[ $(ping localhost -c 4 | wc -l) -gt 0 ]]; }

if exp1 "$1" || exp2
then
   echo Ok!
fi
```